# Build tree table with GWT CellTableBuilder

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to build a tree table like [this](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:basictreegrid) with the new `CellTableBuilder` of "vanilla" `GWT`?
[image]

The [GWT Showcase example](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid) only allows to expand the "top level" rows. My use case requires expansion of multiple row levels.

How can I achieve this with pure `GWT`?

Comment: Is there absolutely no chance to get this done with pure GWT???